# C++ multithreaded pointer to pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a pointer to pointer to pointer, i.e. int*** ptr, where it holds a three dimensional array. Depending on the CPU, I want to have approximately three threads writing and reading at the same time my pointer. For the purpose of simplicity, the ptr won't be redimensioned (I still want to know how to handle multithreading if I had to redimension the pointer). I want to write concurrently to the pointer without having to use mutexes because it would block other threads. How would I do that? I still don't quite understand the atomic template clas...

Thank you! :)

Comment: A mutex is how you *would* handle the concurrency in this ... If you are changing where the pointers point, you do not want other threads looking at the wrong place ...

Comment: Actually, I am not changing the pointer itself; I am changing the value that the pointer points to. Ex: ptr[0][0][0] = something.

Comment: @user2924010 If you really have no resizing going on, i.e: you basically have a `myArray[x][y][z]` with run-time values, then you should be fine with `std::atomic<int>`. This way all the elements are "safe" to read and write. If any of the arrays has to change, then you will require synchronation (mutexes). You could consider wrapping this in a type to handle this outside client code.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan "safe" is correct, but it may be applying safety that the end user doesn't need, which will slow down the code and make it more bulky.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Correct, but he should be aware of it. He might still get into issues since he is talking about reading / writing at the same time.

Comment: Thank you both! :) I'll test the performance difference.

Comment: I think you might get better answers if you explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your threads are running.

All threads can read from a given location without conflict, but it is changing a value (changing the value at the same time, reading a value while it is changing, or using a read value that has changed) that is the problem.

If you've guarenteed that no value will be changed between threads (for example, thread 1 writes to ptr[0][0][x], thread 2 ptr[0][1][x], thread 3 ptr[0][2][x]) you actually don't need to do any mutexes at all.

If you do not have that guarantee, then you have to mutex every read and write of the values.

Redimensioning is essentially changing the pointer value. So if only 1 thread has to deal with the pointer value that is being changed, you don't have to worry about it. Else, mutex on every read and write. So if only 1 thread ever accesses ptr[0][0], and you need to resize ptr[0][0], then you are golden.

If you do not have that guarantee, then you have to mutex every read and write of the values.